# Ошибка на стороне клиента. Код состояния: 401 xNet c#

Tags: c#, post, вконтакте, xnet

У меня возникли странные проблемы. Смотрел как авторизоваться по ссылки в VK.
Но вот в любом случаи у меня HttpStatusCode = Unauthorized
[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код:

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

        string responce = "", error = "";
        try { responce = request.Post("https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username=" + Login + "&password=" + Password).ToString(); }
        catch (HttpException ex) { error = ex.HttpStatusCode.ToString(); }

        if (error == "Unauthorized")
            return false;
        else
        {
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(responce);
            return true;
        }
```

**Как вы поняли я использую xNet библиотеку.** Я передаю ссылку в Post, ну хотя с Get тоже самое.
А именно если я буду вводить даже правильные данные то все равно будет возникать ошибка "**Ошибка на стороне клиента. Код состояния: 401**"

Может быть это с cсылкой что то не так? Если да то где такую найти? Просто я делал все по видео, и ссылку брал именно с него.
**Вот она:** "https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username=login&password=pass"

*На сайте все работает. Т.е я знаю когда у меня прошла авторизация успешно а когда нет. И даже на моей странице вк было подобное сообщение "***Кто то авторизовался на ваш аккаунт***"*

Прошу вашей помощи! А то боюсь застряну с этой проблемой на очень долго!
Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Ну так, вопрос для очистки совести: client_secret поменяли на свой, логин-пароль тоже? А то может чужой client_id и всё остальное? (хорошо, что не запостили пароль, но вообще client_secret ещё более важно прятать)

Comment: POST-запрос? Данные посылаются в URL? Не может быть...

Comment: В любом случае, данные, вставляемые в URL, должны быть перекодированы. 
`HttpUtility.UrlEncode` или `WebUtility.UrlEncode`.

Comment: @AK, нет, client_secret это не мой, он взят с видео. И если не секрет, то что он делает? А то мне бы хотелось узнать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не знаю сам почему так, автор видео сказал что "request.Get" не работает, вот Он и там использовал request.Post, не знаю почему но у него все работает. Но у него какой то другой ответ после ввода данной ссылки.

Спасибо за ответ! Буду пробовать сейчас.

Comment: Вам нужно ощутить разницу между GET и POST запросом.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @aepot, я знаю что такое Get, Post запросы. Просто повторял по видео

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отправить POST-запрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1246377/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81)